# Does anybody know of an issue where RegEnumKeyEx works on XP but not Windows 7, using VB6?

Tags: vb6, registry

I have a program which works fine on XP but just installed it on a Windows 7 machine and this part of code doesn't work. There is no error message it just doesn't retrieve the data.
Other registry operations work okay.

```
Dim n As Long
Dim keyname As String
Dim keyvalue As String
Dim hkey As Long
Dim hkey1 As Long
Dim regopentype As Long
Dim lretval As Long
Dim lkeyvalsize As Long
Dim lpattr As Long
Dim str100 As String * 100
Dim subkeyname As String
Dim lkeyvalue As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim XS As String
Dim v As Variant

    nominals = 0
    keyname = "MX3\NOMINAL"
    lretval = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, keyname, 0, REG_SZ, _ 
              REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, lpattr, hkey, regopentype)
    If lretval <> 0 Then
       MsgBox "Error RegCreateKeyEx"
       Exit Sub
    End If

    If regopentype = 1 Then
       MsgBox "regopentype = 1"
       RegCloseKey (hkey)
       GoTo End_Nominals
    End If

Read_Nominal:
    lkeyvalsize = 100
    subkeyname = str100
    lretval = RegEnumKeyEx(hkey, n, subkeyname, lkeyvalsize, 0, vbNullString, 0, 0)
    If lretval = ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS Then
       GoTo End_Nominals
    End If

    If lretval <> 0 Then
       MsgBox "Error in RegEnumKeyEx"
       GoTo End_Nominals
    End If
    i = InStr(subkeyname, vbNullChar)
    subkeyname = Left$(subkeyname, i - 1)

    ' now get the value at this key
    keyname = "MX3\NOMINAL\" & subkeyname
    lretval = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, keyname, 0, REG_SZ, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, _
                             KEY_ALL_ACCESS, lpattr, hkey1, regopentype)
    If lretval <> 0 Or regopentype <> 2 Then
       MsgBox "Error reading value " & keyname
       GoTo End_Nominals
    End If
    keyvalue = str100
    lkeyvalsize = 100
    lretval = RegQueryValueExString(hkey1, keyname, 0, REG_SZ, keyvalue, lkeyvalsize)
    If lretval <> 0 Then
       MsgBox "Error in RegQueryValue"
       GoTo End_Nominals
    End If

    i = InStr(keyvalue, vbNullChar)
    keyvalue = Left$(keyvalue, i - 1)
    nominals = nominals + 1
    NominalArray(nominals, 1) = subkeyname
    NominalArray(nominals, 2) = keyvalue

    n = n + 1
    GoTo Read_Nominal

End_Nominals:

    RegCloseKey (hkey)
    RegCloseKey (hkey1)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Check out this MSDN article and see if adding the KEY_WOW64_64KEY flag to your call to RegCreateKeyEx function fixes your problem. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My first though would be a permissions issue; UAC in Windows 7 requires elevated permissions to read from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`. Try running as Administrator on the Windows 7 machine and see if you get the expected results.

Another thought is that it could be a 32bit vs 64bit issue. For example, on a 32-bit OS you can read from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\`, but on a 64bit OS, you have to read from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\`.